# What does 10 mean in libgmp10 library?

Tags: version, shared-library

My system has `libgmp.so.10.2.0` while [official source](https://gmplib.org/) says current version is `6.1.2`.

Is this specific to GMP? Would having `libgmp.so.42.0.0` be OK?

Debian adds another number "2" to the mix (ignoring patches).

```
libgmp10:amd64  2:6.0.0+dfsg-6
```

Comment: That's a libtool version, which is usually unrelated to the library's release version.

Comment: How can I get interface number, revision and age then?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, this question is about the number "10" in the libary (and Debian package) name.

Comment: It is a duplicate, 10 is part of the soname (it's the major version).

Comment: I agree that it's not a duplicate and the answers to the other question do not answer this question at all.  @ThomasDickey's answer does!

Answer (score 3):

You're referring to the [libtool version](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Libtool-versioning.html), which is usually unrelated to the library's release version.

A quick look at the sources would show you that the versions are set in [`Makefile.am`](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/Makefile.am#l42), with a comment-block preceding the values giving a summary of the history.

Here's a chunk where you'll see the numbers of the Debian package (version info for libmp is in the last column):

```
#       release   libgmp  libgmpxx libmp 
...
#        5.0.1   10:1:0    6:1:2   4:21:1 
#        5.0.2   10:2:0    6:2:2   4:22:1 
#        5.0.3   10:3:0    6:3:2   4:23:1 
#        5.0.4   10:4:0    6:4:2   4:24:1 
#        5.0.5   10:5:0    6:5:2   4:25:1 
#        5.1.0   11:0:1    7:0:3     -
```

and (current)

```
#        6.1.2   13:2:3    9:2:5     -
```

and

```
# We interpret "implementation changed" in item "1." above as meaning any 
# release, ie. the REVISION is incremented every time (if nothing else). 
# Even if we thought the code generated will be identical on all systems, 
# it's still good to get the shared library filename (like 
# libgmpxx.so.3.0.4) incrementing, to make it clear which GMP it's from. 

LIBGMP_LT_CURRENT    = 13
LIBGMP_LT_REVISION   = 2
LIBGMP_LT_AGE        = 3

LIBGMPXX_LT_CURRENT  = 9
LIBGMPXX_LT_REVISION = 2
LIBGMPXX_LT_AGE      = 5
```

Comment: A link to `Makefile.am`, if available, would be helpful. And some elaboration would also be useful. For example, some explanation of the meaning of `CURRENT`, `REVISION`, `AGE`. Finally, this doesn't seem to agree with the OPs observation. He said `6.1.2` corresponds to `10:2:0`, but in your table it seems to correspond to `13:2:3`. Disclaimer: it's the middle of the night here, so I may not be with it. Regardless, a little more explanation would not hurt.

Comment: It's *related* to the information given to `libtool`, since that is used to calculate the soname. But the number used in the library and package name is the soname, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

[Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html#s-sharedlibs-runtime) requires changing package name whenever SONAME changes (as others correctly pointed out the relationship to version numbers). The interface number is `10` in releases `5.0.x` so it's a good idea to make it part of the package name.

Note that release `5.1.0` has `age = 1` which means it could "provide" both interface numbers `10` and `11`. Not sure whether Debian actually does this.

Comment: from the same link: "_Normally_, the run-time shared library and its SONAME symlink _should be placed in a package named **librarynamesoversion**_, where _soversion_ is the version number in the _SONAME_ of the shared library_...